# Parse Cloud - make a GET endpoint

Tags: parse-platform

I have made simple cloud function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("clientsnames", function(request, response) {
      var query = new Parse.Query("Clients");
      query.select('name')
      query.find({
          success: function(results) {
              response.success(results)
          },
          error: function() {
              response.error("Failed");
          }
      })
});
```

But to call it I always must use POST

```
curl -s -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d "{}" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/functions/clients
```

Which is, of course, a bad idea, and the request itself is obviously should be GET. But when I use GET with this request, I just get 404 (Document not found).

Is it possible to define a GET endpoint using Parse Cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Express js hosted on Parse CloudCode to setup custom endpoints
That way you can configure GET, POST without even using the Parse keys in the headers.

Head over to 
https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webhooks for detailed example